# Android: Navigation Drawer Icons

Tags: java, android, arraylist, navigation-drawer, android-resources

I am using template from [AndroidHive: Material Design](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) and decide to add some icon on each navigation drawer row.
I already modified the model NavDrawerItem, getter and setter for icon was added.

```
// Constructor
public NavDrawerItem(boolean showNotify, String title, int icon) {
    this.showNotify = showNotify;
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getIcon(){
    return icon;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setIcon(int icon){
    this.icon = icon;
}
```

Also its adapter (NavigationDrawerAdapter) was modified, adding icon support

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NavDrawerItem current = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.getIcon());
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_drawer);
    }
}
```

I know this drawer was added on onCreate method of FragmentDrawer.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // drawer labels
    titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
    icons = getActivity().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icon);
}
```

This is my array from string.xml

```
<string-array name="nav_drawer_labels">
    <item>@string/nav_item_home</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_data_visualization</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_pending_item</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_my_profile</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_about_us</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="nav_drawer_icon">
    <item>@drawable/ic_home</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_data_visualization</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_pending_item</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_profile_drawer</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_about</item>
</string-array>
```

And my navigation drawer item was populated from resource using this piece of code in FragmentDrawer.java

```
public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
    List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();

    // preparing navigation drawer items
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
        navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
        System.out.println(titles[i]);

        navItem.setIcon(icons[i]);
        System.out.println(icons[i]);

        data.add(navItem);
    }
    return data;
}
```

**My problem is populating icon from resource**, in the code above System.out.println(icons[i]); always give me 0 value. I think thats why I can't set imageResource of my navigation drawer icon.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can use android design support library to create NavigationDrawer easily...  follow this link    http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: try getDrawable(icons[i])

Comment: Your link was amazing, Harrish. But that things should change the whole project. I think I'll go on solving this problem first. Where I should use getDrawable, Harish?

Comment: holder.icon.setImageResource(getDrawable(current.getIcon()));

Comment: It doesn't work, Harrish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in line:

```
icons = getActivity().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icon);
```

To read resources id's from array you can use this code:

```
icons = new int[titles.length];
TypedArray iconsArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icon);
for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++)
    icons[i] = iconsArray.getResourceId(i, -1);

iconsArray.recycle();
```

But probably the best action will be to use [NavigationView](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

Comment: Thank you, Kamil. You saved my day!